# How make a LINQ Select, GroupBy and Count from a List of Lists?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have a `List<IEnumerable<Foo>>`

This makes an list like this:

```
{
    [
      {a: 1, b: 2},
      {a: 1, b: 3}
    ],
    [{a: 1, b: 2}]
}
```

And i need to arrange it in this way, grouping the objects by the a and b values. I was no able to make a group query to anything like the example below.

```
{
   {a: 1, b: 2, count: 2},
   {a: 1, b: 3, count: 1}
}
```

Edit: 
Here's the code that i have and the output:

```
var list = new List<object>();
foreach (var f in fooList)
{
    var x = from y in f
            group y by new { y.a, y.b } into z
            select new
            {
                Foo = z.Key,
                Count = z.Count()
            };
    a.Add(x);
}
```

Output:

```
[
  {
     "Foo": {
         "a": 1,
         "b": 2
     },
     "count": 1
  },
  {
     "Foo": {
         "a": 1,
         "b": 2
     },
     "count": 1
  },
  {
     "Foo": {
         "a": 1,
         "b": 3
     },
     "count": 1
  }
],
```

Comment: Please show us what you've tried.

Comment: If `Foo` Equality is determined by `a`and `b`, you could do this with a `Dictionary<Foo, int>`.

Comment: Sorry, @ParrishHusband, i didn't understood what you mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this will work:

```
var list = new List<List<Foo>>();
list.Add(new List<Foo> {new Foo {A = 1, B = 2}, new Foo {A = 1, B = 3}});
list.Add(new List<Foo> {new Foo {A = 1, B = 2}});

var result = list.SelectMany(l => l)
    .GroupBy(l => new {l.A, l.B})
    .Select(grp => new {A = grp.Key.A, B = grp.Key.B, Count = grp.Count()});
```

First the list gets flattened with `SelectMany()`. After that we `GroupBy` multiple values by using an anonymous object. After grouping we are selecting the initial values and the count out of the grouping into an anonymous object.

---

It seems like you want your result to be serialized. Using [Json.Net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json), this will be the output:

```
[
   {
      "A":1,
      "B":2,
      "Count":2
   },
   {
      "A":1,
      "B":3,
      "Count":1
   }
]
```

Comment: The project already do the parsing for Json, but thanks. This is exactly what i need.

Answer (score 0):

You have to flatten your first list, as the nested level is irrelevant to your desired result. This shows how to flatten. I think your GroupBy is correct.

```
    List<List<Foo>> list = new List<List<Foo>>();
    list.Add(new List<Foo>());
    list[0].Add(new Foo { a = 1, b = 2 });
    list[0].Add(new Foo { a = 1, b = 3 });
    var subList = new List<Foo>();
    subList.Add(new Foo { a = 1, b = 2 });
    list.Add(subList);
    var flat = list.SelectMany(i => i);
    var grouped = from foo in flat group foo by new { foo.a, foo.b } into g select g;
    Assert.AreEqual(true, grouped.First().Count() == 2);
    Assert.AreEqual(true, grouped.Last().Count() == 1);
```